# disconjugacy of a self adjoint operator

Tags: self-adjoint-operators

How we can cheek if this defference equation $-\Delta^2 y(t)=0$ is disconjugate or not?
We have this definition:
We say that the difference equation $\Delta (p(t-1)\Delta y(t-1))+q(t)y(t)=0$ is "disconjugate" on $[a, b+
2]=\{a, a+1,...,b+2\}$ provided that no nontrivial solution of $\Delta (p(t-1)\Delta y(t-1))+q(t)y(t)=0$ has two or more generalized zeros on
[a, b + 2].

What is a generalized zero?

Comment: Maybe you could link to one of [these](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=%22disconjugate%22+%22generalized+zero%22) for context.

Comment: Thank you for your help